# Calling a function when QGraphicsScene is scrolled

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside

Lets say that there are two subclasses of `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene`.

I want to run a function when `QGraphicsScene` is scrolled.

Like in `QPushButton`, there is a function named `clicked` and it can call a function when we click the button. Similarly, is there any function similar to that which can call a function when `QGraphicsScene` is scrolled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all Qt scroll areas, QGraphicsView has two scrollbars, and those are used by all scroll areas for that purposes, even if they are hidden. So, what you're looking for, is to connect to the [`valueChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged) signal:

```
    self.graphicsView.horizontalScollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.myFunction)
    self.graphicsView.verticalScollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.myFunction)
```